# Prometheus Config reload Annotation for Grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I want to show in Grafana with an Annotation if there is a successful Prometheus config reload.

Grafana v6.3.5 &
Prometheus v2.12.0

I imported an existing Dashboard for internal Prometheus Stats and saw that within this Dashboard they use the following Statement as Annotion: `sum(changes(prometheus_config_last_reload_success_timestamp_seconds[10m]))`

Sadly this does not work and I am not sure how to properly use the metric to create Annotations.
 How can I use this Metric to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a recent version of Grafana, you don't need this expression any more. There is a feature to [display annotations base on series value](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/11789).

If you want in annotations the successful reloads of configuration, you can simply use the value of the metric `prometheus_config_last_reload_success_timestamp_seconds`, multiplied by 1000 to have the timestamp in msec (as expected by Grafana). And there is a tick box at the bottom of the annotation panel `Series value as timestamp` to active.

Save your dashboard and that's all.

Comment: turns out this was actually a bug with another annotation in the Dashboard the "down" Annotation. If that one was enabled, then the reloads would not show. I also updated my statement to yours, since it seems cleaner. Thank you!